# blank space when browse with iphone's safari&chrome

Tags: html, iphone, responsive-design

My website is http://www.rcdecolighting.cn/about-us/showroom

A responsive page, when browse with iphone'safari&chrome, there will be a blank space in the right side. But disappear in chrome(pc)'s debug tool.
I have check code many times, but can't figure it out.

There are some hint may be help:

when click on the search button, there will be a search layer appear on the top. I check the width of the layer is 391,but width of body is 375.
I have set the width of the layer to the same with body width when page onload, but still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

bro, when u do responsive... always use width in '%' .
So try to set your width in %.
Thank you.

Comment: would u please give me some hint?  which setting of element or elements lead to my problem?